# I'm missing old alt-f2 in unity

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm missing the good old alt-f2 in unity. Is there a way to add this feature to unity? Are they some programs that work reasonably similar to alt-f2 in the older gnome?

Comment: Alt+F2 should still work in Unity. It looks like it just brings up the dash, but actually the textbox at the top of this dash is a Run Command textbox, rather than a search box. Is this not working for you? If not, can you give some examples of commands that you're unable to run this way? (Or is the problem that Alt+F2, when pressed, is having no effect at all?)

Comment: For example, I have a cmd alias in my ~/bin directory which points to gnome-terminal. Whenever, I type cmd in that box and hit enter it doesn't open a console. However, if I type ~/bin/cmd it works.

Comment: Do you have `~/bin` in your path?

Comment: I think so. I have added it to my ~/.bashrc

Comment: From what you're saying in these comments, the problem is not that the Run Command textbox doesn't work, but that it doesn't work for certain specific actions. You should edit your post to reflect this, in detail. ....It occurs to me to ask, have you logged out and back in since you created this command alias and added it to your PATH? Also, why did you put it in `.bashrc` rather than `.profile`? If you put it in `.profile` (and then log out and back in to your Unity session), does that fix the problem?

Comment: Eliah, that's not the only problem. The older version had completion too, so I didn't have to type the complete name. For example, I could just type ged instead of gedit. This feature is very important and saves a lot of time.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Comment: You can use xfrun from xubuntu